# SQL rollup query using COMPUTE and COMPUTE BY

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table with two columns (FileExtension and FileSize), like below:

```
FileType FileSize
---------------------------
dll      129
bak      2323
ext      242424
ini      40
bak      532
log      32
bak      3253
dll      9094
bak      234
txt      587
dll      1000
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query, possibly using a combination of ROLLUP, or COMPUTE, that will provide the top 3 values in the FileTypes column, based on the largest FileSize. A Total column will be included on the bottom of the report that provides a sum of all of the values in FileSize column. The query results would be something like:

```
FileType    FileExtension
-------------------------------
ext         242424
dll         10223
bak         6342
Total       259648
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this query would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is basic grouping:

```
;with cte as (
select top 3 FileType, sum(FileSize) as FileExtension 
from TableName
group by FileType
order by FileExtension desc
)
select * from cte
union all
select 'Total', sum(FileExtension) from cte
```

If I understand correctly:

```
;with cte as (
    select top 3 FileType, sum(FileSize) as FileExtension 
    from TableName
    group by FileType
    order by FileExtension desc
    )
    select * from cte
    union all
    select 'Total', sum(FileSize) from TableName
```

Comment: No, the total should be for the entire table.

Comment: This query is great, and is almost what I needed. Is there a way to get a sum of all values in the FileSize column for the last 'Total' row?

Comment: @MelissaB, see updated answer if I anderstand correctly you need top 3 rows but in total sum of all rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total `FileSize` values per `FileType` and the grand total `FileSize` in a single query like this:

```
SELECT
  FileType,
  TotalSize = SUM(FileSize)
FROM
  dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(FileType)
;
```

As a result of the ROLLUP grouping function, you will have an additional row, with the `TotalSize` value being the sum of all individual `TotalSize` values and `FileType` set to NULL.

To get only the top three totals and the grand total, you can just sort the results in the descending order of `TotalSize` and add `TOP (4)` to the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT TOP (4)
  FileType,
  TotalSize = SUM(FileSize)
FROM
  dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(FileType)
ORDER BY
  TotalSize DESC
;
```

This will give you almost what you want. You will only need to replace the null `FileType` with `'Total'` and move the grand total row to the end of the result set.

The first problem is easy: just use the `COALESCE` function. To solve the second one, you could use the above query as a derived table and sort the results once again, as shown in the below [final query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ee5e/3):

```
SELECT
  FileType = COALESCE(FileType, 'Total'),
  TotalSize
FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (4)
      FileType,
      TotalSize = SUM(FileSize)
    FROM
      dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY
      ROLLUP(FileType)
    ORDER BY
      TotalSize DESC
  ) AS s
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN FileType IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,
  TotalSize DESC
;
```

The outer query's first sorting criterion is a CASE expression that evaluates to 1 for the grand total row (based on the fact that its `FileType` is null) and to 0 for every other. The ascending order on that result makes sure the grand total row ends up at the bottom of the set.

Note that if the `FileType` column had NULLs of its own, the above query wouldn't work correctly if the NULL result was one of the top three. You would then need a way to distinguish between a NULL that comes from the source dataset and the one produced by the ROLLUP function. This is where you can use the [GROUPING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx) function, which

> Indicates whether a specified column expression in a GROUP BY list is aggregated or not. GROUPING returns 1 for aggregated or 0 for not aggregated in the result set.

So, if `GROUPING(FileType)` returned 1, that would be the roll-up row, otherwise it would be a `FileType` sub-total. The result of the function could be easily used both to substitute the `'Total'` for the column value and to sort the results for the final output. The only issue would be, since the function makes sense only in the immediate context of a GROUP BY query but sorting on the function's results would be performed at a later stage, you would probably need to return those results as a column of the derived table for later use. The below [rewrite of the previous query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ee5e/5) shows exactly how:

```
SELECT
  FileType = CASE IsRollup WHEN 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE FileType END,
  TotalSize
FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (4)
      FileType,
      TotalSize = SUM(FileSize),
      IsRollup  = GROUPING(FileType)
    FROM
      dbo.YourTable
    GROUP BY
      ROLLUP(FileType)
    ORDER BY
      TotalSize DESC
  ) AS s
ORDER BY
  IsRollup  ASC,
  TotalSize DESC
;
```

Comment: You can use the [GROUPING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx) function to distinguish a grouped column from possible NULL values. That's much clearer than using COALESCE. Same goes for your sorting statement.

Comment: @TT.: Yes, I know about this function. The null check seems enough for this particular case but it would make sense to show the proper way of working with roll-up rows in general. So, I'll probably update my answer later, thanks for bringing this up.